# Python import error, "'modules' is not a package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, module, package

I keep getting this error even though I downloaded the "modules" library.

```bash
No module named 'modules.MainWindow'; 
'modules' is not a package
```

here's the code

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from modules.MainWindow import MainWindow


version = "2.0.1"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried downloading 'modules' but it returned requirement already satisfied

Comment: From where do you get `from modules.MainWindow import MainWindow` some kind of tutorial? Copying from othe code?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the tutorial on eric6 found [here](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/MiniBrowser/index.html). If so, modules does not have to be installed, it is just the name of the folder in which your mainwindow.py resides.

First, make sure that you use the correct file (e.g. `mainwindow` instead of `MainWindow`) without the `.py` extension. This should fix your error.

Also, maybe rename the folder you are using to something different. The name `modules` is already used in `sys`, which might cause confusion when trying to install it.

To be more exact, this should fix the error:

```
from modules.mainwindow import MainWindow
```

Comment: it didnt fix it any other suggestions